# Why can @requestparam get file upload data in SpringMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

@requestparam functions like request.getquerystring (). Why does she receive a multipart/form-data type contentType when @requestbody cannot?Please tell me why?

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/uploadFileByUserTrainId", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    @Student({Student.Authority.A, Student.Authority.B, Student.Authority.C})
    public WebMessage uploadFileByUserTrainId(
            @RequestParam(value = "document", required = false) MultipartFile multipartFile,
            @RequestParam(value = "documetnRe", required = false) MultipartFile multipartFileRe,
            @RequestParam("id") long id,
            @RequestParam(value = "documentFileType", required = false) String fileType,
            @RequestParam(value = "documentFileReType", required = false) String fileReType,
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
      // todo
    }
```

Comment: `Requestbody` means **request parameters in json format**. Files can not be uploaded in json format.

Comment: So why does @requestparam receive files?

Comment: `requestparam` is not in json format and can contains any format including `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: You mean @requestparam can get it as long as it is not in json format?

Comment: Yes. @requestparam is exactly for get params in formats other than json.

Comment: Okay, so that's the logic that's going to be handled internally by Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nothing wrong using `@RequestParam` with `Multipart file.`

`@RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument supporting the same method argument types. The main difference is that when the method argument is not a String, @RequestParam relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or PropertyEditor`

Comment: The main difference is that when the method argument is not a String, @RequestParam relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or PropertyEditor. I don't quite understand this sentence.

Comment: Here you are looking for Type Conversion As per spring documentation  String-based values extracted from the request including request parameters, path variables, request headers, and cookie values may need to be converted to the target type of the method parameter or field (e.g., binding a request parameter to a field in an @ModelAttribute parameter) they’re bound to. If the target type is not String, Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type. All simple types such as int, long, Date, etc. are supported.

Comment: In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form data,
and parts in multipart requests. The official document said so, I understand some, thank you.